# Alternative to .trimmingCharacters to get my solution accepted by Coderbytes

Tags: swift, swift2

On my `Xcode` playground the following snippet trims the `whitespaces` from any `String` (as I want).

```
let trimmed = "   hello   ".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

When I try to submit a solution using this syntax to Coderbytes it throws:

> /tmp/005424279/main.swift:5:17: error: value of type 'String' has no
>   member 'trimmingCharacters' let trimmed = "     hello      ".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

The same thing happens when I try the `Swift2` version of

```
 let trimmed = "   hello   ".stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(in: .whitespaces)
```

There is no Intelligence on Coderbytes - and I'm really stumped for what would work to get my solution accepted. (I know I should just be happy I've solved the puzzle and not worry about Coderbyte accepting it - but, you know, you get competitive about building up a ranking!

Comment: Try adding `import Foundation`. This functionality is provided by the `Foundation` framework.

Comment: Thank you. Thank worked. I'm surprised - I haven't come across It before and I thought Foundation was baked into Coderbytes interface...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Swift version they are using.

For Swift 4 I used this:

```
import Foundation

let trimmed = "        hellloo     ".trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
print(trimmed)
```